# What set for ASP.NET Membership provider name in forms based authentication?

Tags: 2010, web-part, claims-based-auth

I want created a custom login page . I set Claims Based Authentication my site .

When i Enable Forms Based Authentication (FBA) , what value set for :

**ASP.NET Membership provider name**

**ASP.NET Role manager name**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [This](http://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/sharepoint-2010-claims-authentication-custom-login-form-part-1-modifying-your-config-files/) link . it is useful for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this yet:
http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/05/06/configuring-claims-and-forms-based-authentication-for-use-with-an.aspx

I've followed through with those instructions successfully on one of my farms that uses LDAP as it's membership provider, and it worked like a charm.  In there she uses LdapMember and LdapRole for the names.

Comment: Yes, i use . but i have many web application and they are claims and classic base. when i use this code other web application get error :(

Answer (score 0):

It is the name of membership and role provider you implemented and configured to use in web.config.

Check here for details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252020.aspx

Comment: Thanks , but i want Configuring claims and forms based authentication for use with an *LDAP provider* in SharePoint 2010